# Existing entity put in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

For some reason, I've been under the impression that writing an existing entity is just as expensive, if not more, than writing a new entity, so a lot of my code has focused on ways of breaking entities into smaller entities so that when I modify a property, it incurs less write costs. However, looking now at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing), it states that an existing entity put has the following costs:

> 1 write + 4 writes per modified indexed property value + 2 writes per
>   modified composite index value

Before I go around changing the entire structure of my code, I want to be sure I understand the details. What exactly qualifies an index as "modified"? Say I have 4 indexed string properties and no composite indexes. To put this as a new entity would cost 10 writes `(2 + 2(indexed properties))`. Say I now modify one of these string properties and put it back. Would that cost 5 writes only `(1 + 4 per modified index)`? Am I missing anything? Are there any things I should take into consideration?

And what if I had 4 indexed properties and 1 non-indexed property, and I modify only the non-indexed property - this will only cost me 1 write to re-put?

Comment: Also, this is really easy to test in SDK 1.7.1 now that AppStats gives stats on the cost of operations (must be enabled). It will tell you exactly how many writes each operation took. Really useful new feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your suppositions are correct. It helps if you know what the writes are for: The 1 write is for the entity itself; the 2 writes per indexed property on create are for the ascending and descending single property indexes for each property, and the 4 writes per indexed property on update are to delete the old value and insert the new value into those ascending and descending indexes.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran an experiment where I updated a model that has 3 indexed properties (one of those being a list), and 4 unindexed properties.

I used a mapreduce run to update one of the unindexed properties and Put() the entity.

If I did my math right, I've verified that it only took 1 write op per entity, even though there were 3 indexed properties (that weren't updated).

(my math might have been a bit iffy since I used mapreduce, and mapreduce itself issues a bunch of datastore writes.  I did a separate experiment to estimate the # of mapreduce writes, so I've accounted for it).